# SQL Component Connection issue in IDE

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, dbexpress

Good evening guys.

I'm currently trying to get started on development of a project to make my own life a little easier. Essentially, i want to connect to a `MySQL` database running on a remote server, and then go from there with a few various options for usage. The database in question is used for a `Joomla!` installation, and my focus will primarily be managing articles from a desktop application (as opposed to using the administrator backend on the website).

I've allowed my own host access to the remote servers (via the `CPanel` web interface used by my hosting provider), and ensured that `LIBMYSQL.dll` is inside the `RAD Studio\9.0\bin` folder and again inside my executables folder (so as to avoid any of the issues related to being unable to init. the driver). I've connected to the server successfully by using `MySQL Workbench` and can freely query the table. Now, onto the problem.

**This is my first database application so please understand that a simplified or excessive explanation may be needed**

I'm having issues setting some of the component properties at design time. I've got a `TSQLConnection` component, a `TSQLDataSet` component, and a `TSQLTable` component. I've set up the server properties in `TSQLConnection` to work with my server.

However, if i try to retrieve anything from the database inside the `Delphi XE2` IDE (i.e. the login prompt appears) such as changing `Active` property to true, i get a `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10061)` error (where 'x' relates to part of my servers IP).

If i run the application itself though, and then click on the "connect" button i've got on the interface, it connects fine with no errors. I added `ShowMessage` routines to the `AfterConnect`, `AfterDisconnect`, and `OnLogin` events of `TSQLConnection` to verify it was actually going through, and all of them functioned as i'd expect when successful. As i've not coded for it to do anything outside of that (due to still learning the basics), there's no data visible on the interface for me to work with, but the connection at least appears to be there.

To clarify, i can connect from the application i developed (as well as from `MySQL Workbench`, but not from within the Delphi IDE itself.

So, where am i going wrong with this?

I'm guessing it's probably some oversight by myself due to my lack of knowledge on the subject of databases, but i'm very keen to expand out of the desktop environment and start working with some more areas of the IT world (without losing the development side of things that i enjoy so much).

Comment: Set the `LoginPrompt` property of the `TSQLConnection` component to false to avoid the login prompt dialog shows and also check the values of the `params` property.

Comment: 10061 is connection refused, it can be an internet connection problem rather then something wrong with your setup (other than IP/port perhaps). Make sure the IDE is allowed to go online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SertacAkyuz pointed out in the original comments, it was indeed an issue related to my connection, specifically Firewall settings. I had assumed that "Connection Refused" was related to the connection attempt being made, but being actively refused by the remote server. The more you know.